# Is it safe to uninstall apps from AppStore from Finder instead of Launchpad

Tags: macos, mac, applications, install

Apple [tells](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102610) us to uninstall apps from AppStore by using Launchpad and apps not from AppStore by using Finder. Is it safe to use Finder for both "kinds" of apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define "safe", we have to define what the risks might be. At worst, you'll be leaving some executable code on the disk, which may either just take up space, or possibly get executed and cause a problem. *(E.g. Because some other part of it is missing, or because it is out of date.)*

Typically, by deleting the app itself from Applications, all that will be left is a few preference files in the user's Library, and these are a few kilobytes in size, so you'd need tens of thousands of them before they would take up any significant space.

Apps from the App Store are self-contained within their .app bundle. So it's easy to delete them, and you know that everything is gone. (Except for the pref files, as above.) You can do this in the Finder, or in Launchpad.

Most apps from other sources follow this model too; but some apps install other components to folders in `/Library`, if they need special capabilities or additional flexibility. Such apps will usually use an Installer .pkg file to install themselves. You should follow the developer's instructions for uninstalling.

I suspect that Launchpad doesn't offer deleting third-party apps because it can't be sure whether they need to be uninstalled more diligently, or not.

Comment: Note: some apps have a built-in uninstaller. Right-click on an app and click Show Package Contents. This will open the app 'package' in a directory format. Look inside this directory for an uninstaller app.

Comment: Not just preference files in the user's library are left behind, but also a container (since they all are sandboxed), which is more than a few kilobytes.

Comment: *Also...* If you remove an app that is in Launchpad via the Finder it will usually not also remove the App's icon from Launchpad. So you will have to remove it from launchpad as well. I did this recently both with a couple of Apple apps and a couple of 3rd party apps. The Launchpad icon for each app had to *also* be removed manually.

Comment: @Redarm The Container usually contains sym links to the folders that the app can access, plus the plists. It might be a bit more, but not much. You can of course delete the named Containers, and search for Application Support folders, etc. to reclaw some Mb.

Comment: @benwiggy The links can be ignored yes, but... anything that's not a link can grow to hundreds of MB, if not GB.

Comment: @Redarm Only if the app specifically saves large amounts of data there for some reason. That's fairly unusual. But of course you can use a disk sweeper.

Answer (score 1):

Your link states that the Launchpad provides "a convenient way" to delete apps. It's just a convenience feature, not the only way.

You can delete AppStore apps through Finder or Launchpad equally safely.

Note that app related settings are generally not removed by this method. Consider this a feature should you choose to re-install in the future. But if you want rid completely then look into a cleanup app such as [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). Other apps exist but I couldn't vouch for them other than I've used AppCleaner for quite some years.

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading that page.

Apple's web page  you quote has as its first paragraph

> Deleting or uninstalling an app removes it from your Mac and makes the storage space it was using available for other items. You can do this from Launchpad or the Finder.

So Apple does NOT tell his to uninstall using Launchpad and not Finder. It says you can use either.

The difference on that page is that Launchpad can only  delete Apps downloaded from the App Store. For Finder it says any app and does not mention where it was installed from.